# Elmah - log session specific info

Tags: session, elmah

I want to add some addtional information from session to the Elmah log. It's the UserID which is in session so we know who error relates to. I've been playing around adding ErrorLog_Logged to the global.ascx. How do I add some addtional info to the error detail so I can see the UserID in the axd file. Cheers, Chris.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912383/logging-username-with-elmah-for-wcf-webservices), seems similar to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That seems to be adding an additional log item rather than amending the current one. When I say userid it is a custom value stored in Session.