# Clarification on how Elmah set the Logged in User Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

I was searching on how the logged in user name was set using ELmah.

The closer i came is the below link

[Logging username with Elmah for WCF Webservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912383/logging-username-with-elmah-for-wcf-webservices)

> Elmah take the user from Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name and not
>   from HttpContext.Current.User

To get more clarity on this does the thread takes Nnme from the windows log on" ?

Or will it log the name if i set `HttpContext.Current.User` ?

How does it work. How application architecture should be to make ELMAH feasible to log UserName ?

Thanks

Comment: Scott Hanselman has a [great post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx) on the differences of these two. there is also [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843271/whats-the-difference-between-httpcontext-current-user-and-thread-currentprincip) derived from these two identity types.

Comment: @BradChristie Thanks for those Excellent links! So i assume ELMAH uses the Thread identity ?