# Elmah for WCF for exception handling

Tags: wcf, elmah

Could ELMAH be used to handle exceptions from/inside WCF?

Comment: Check out this existing answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895901/exception-logging-for-wcf-services-using-elmah

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Elmah.Everywhere](http://nuget.org/packages/Elmah.Everywhere) it works with ASP.NET, ASP.NET.MVC, Silverlight, WCF and WPF