# ELMAH not logging in WCF

Tags: wcf, error-handling, elmah

I've implemented the solution explained here: [Exception Logging for WCF Services using ELMAH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895901/exception-logging-for-wcf-services-using-elmah)

When I debug my code, the ProvideFault in the ErrorHandler is executed correctly and the line which calls ELMAH is also hit:
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(error);

However ELMAH does not log any errors and doesn't send an email (both are set up in the web.config). But if I call ELMAHS log method directly, ELMAH creates a log entry in the database:
Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log(new Elmah.Error(error));

Anyone SO's who've had this problem?

All input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what could be wrong from what you provide in your question but try going through all the steps outlined in [this blog post.](https://lbenotes.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/getting-elmah-to-work-with-wcf-services-hosted-in-iis/)

Comment: I've followed the article which is at the bottom of the blog post. My implementation is excactly the same. I just can't figure out why the Log-method works, but the generic ELMAH handling does not.

Answer (score 0):

I was puzzled before - now I'm even more puzzled! I tried to upload my solution and it works on IIS?! I doesn't work when i test i locally, but works on the server. Why is a mystery to me...